# AWS: API Gateway Authorizer using access token given from ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a project that needs to make use of `Lambda` functions which are triggered by `API Gateway` with protected authorizer, i have set the resource method to require an authorization header which is the `token id` given in Cognito's authentication response. Basically all protected routes in the application are handled by `ALB` which will always check if the requested route is protected and if so then redirect to cognito's `sign-in` in case there is no session, after the authentication is successful, the Load Balancer will redirect the request to the application with additional headers, which are:

- x-amzn-oidc-data
- x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken

Both are in a manner of speaking `JWT` with user claims from the authentication. Normally the `API Gateway` endpoint protected by cognito authorizer requires a `token id` which is easily retreived using the `implicit flow` in cognito's authentication, but the `ALB` is using the `authorization code` flow which only gives a session code. Both data from `x-amzn-oidc-data` and `token id` looks the same but when i try to access the endpoint using the data from `ALB` i only get `unauthorized`.

The ideal flow goes like this:
[image: ALB identity with Lambda]

I know i could avoid all this process by just implementing the `Lambda` function directly to `ALB` as trigger but my project is only looking for automated deployments and `CloudFormation` still does not support `Lambda` implementations for `ELB`.

**TL:DR**

The simple question is: How can i grant access in `API Gateway` using a token given by authorization from `ALB`?

Comment: You are better off adding a resource server to your aws cognito app integration.
Checkout reference links below. - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-define-resource-servers.html - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-resource-servers.html

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I'm facing the same problem, but I'm not using Cognito. Thanks